# Angular in 60ish minutes - What's wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have started to learn Angular and am following the [Angular in 60 minutes](http://fastandfluid.com/publicdownloads/AngularJSIn60MinutesIsh_DanWahlin_May2013.pdf) as a first step. On page-48, there is an example code as shown below, which is a `simple controller` to display the contents of `customers` property in the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="container" ng-controller="SimpleController">
  <h3>Adding a simple controller</h3>
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="cust in customers">
    {{cust.name}} - {{cust.city}}
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <script>
  function SimpleController($scope) {
   $scope.customers = [
    {name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York'},
    {name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'Miami'},
    {name: 'Moan Doe', city: 'Montreal'}
   ];
  }
 </script>
 <script src="/usr/local/angular-1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected output is:

> **Adding a simple controller**
>
> - John Doe - New York
> - Jane Doe - Miami
> - Moan Doe - Montreal

But I can't see the bulleted items. I have been plucking my hairs for quite some time. Thought I will ask the community before I go bald. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: use @user3906922's answer, it's better, also you can just add link to earlier angular(for example 1.1.*)

Comment: Not sure, why someone would down vote this question.

Comment: i think this a popular question for angular. I'm not downvote your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two items that fixed the code.

1. I was fiddling around figured the order of  tags does matter. The `<script>` tag reference to `angular.js` should appear first before the `<script>` tag containing the controller methods.
2. As @user3906922 suggested, the global controller functions doesn't help in angular 1.3.16. I defined a module and controller and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Using version 1.3.16, you cannot longer just declare a global controller function.
Instead, define a module and a controller:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.customers = [
                {name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York'},
                {name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'Miami'},
                {name: 'Moan Doe', city: 'Montreal'}
            ];
        });
```

In your html, add `ng-app` with the correct module name:

```
<body ng-app="app">
```

Comment: Thanks @user3906922. But it didn't help me. Still the same.

Comment: No errors. But didn't get the expected output either.

Comment: check this plunker, its similar to your code, only i switched between the scripts tags http://plnkr.co/edit/1IMKgMSXdMErs2q5cOxX?p=preview

Comment: I just posted an answer after fiddling with script tags switch. Thanks for the link.